# I'm creating an FPS game and I can't work out how to loop the shoot animation of the enemy I've attached the script to until my player dies

Tags: c#, if-statement, animation, unity-game-engine

The script below is attached to the enemy on my game.

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator attack;

    Transform player;

    UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent nav;



    void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

            nav = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent> ();

    }
```

The code just below is getting the enemy to stop at a certain distance and shoot from the trigger "Attack". (Below and above are all the same code).

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


        nav.SetDestination(player.position);
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, player.position);
        if (distance < 10f)
        {


            Animator an = GetComponent<Animator>();
                an.SetTrigger("Attack");

        }


        Debug.Log("distance" + distance);


    }

}
```

This script basically uses the Nav Agent to make the enemy go towards my player and to start a shoot animation when the enemy is at a certain range.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you edit your question and remove its contents? People no longer will understand your question if they run into the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a boolean for the check instead of a Trigger. You should change your code to set the boolean Attacking to false when the player is not in range and set the boolean to true when the player is in range for attacking. Also, make sure your animation clip loop is ticked on.